# Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[NgForOf -> TemplateRef]

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angularjs-directive, angular7

i need to create a `Directive` for validate show button for user or not .

i create a directive in `SahreMudole`  :

```
    @Directive({
  selector: '[appValidatePermission]'
})
export class ValidatePermissionDirective implements OnInit {

  constructor(private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
              private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef
    ,         private dynamic: DynamicPermissionService) { }

  // tslint:disable-next-line:no-input-rename
  @Input('AccessName') AccessName: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.ValidateAccessPemission(this.AccessName);
  }
  ValidateAccessPemission(item: string) {
    if (this.FindAceess(item)) {
      console.log('in d true');
      this.viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
    } else {
      console.log(' in dfalse');
      this.viewContainerRef.clear();
    }
  }

  FindAceess(acess: string): boolean {
    const find = this.dynamic.dynamicModel.filter(x =>
      x.actionsVM.filter(z => z.actionEnglishName === acess));
    if (find == null) {
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
  }
}
```

and in shareMudole :

```
   @NgModule({
  declarations: [ValidatePermissionDirective],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [ValidatePermissionDirective]
})
export class SharedModule {

    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
      return {
        ngModule: SharedModule,
        providers: [ValidatePermissionDirective]
      };
  }
}
```

and i use shareModule in AdminPanme.Module :

```
imports: [
SharedModule,
```

]

and i call that in html code :

```
  <span appValidatePermission [AccessName]='GetRoleList'>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </span>
```

but it show me this error :

> Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[NgForOf -> TemplateRef]

whats the problem ? how can i solve this problem ???

Comment: you have ValidatePermissionDirective in both declarations and providers, why?

Comment: @FatemeFazli no specific reason . I deleted it from the providers, but it also makes a error

Comment: do you have ngFor or ngIf in your code without * sign?

Comment: @FatemeFazli no